# Using the exec method in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have been following a series of tutorials on Node.js.  To demonstrate child processes using exec, I have been given the code below under the file of exec.js   When I go to the command line for node, I type in

```
node exec.js
```

then nothing happens.  Why would this be?

var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec("open http://www.linkedin.com");

Comment: @jfriend00 his code is fine and works for me. [exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) takes the command and args as one big honking string. Maybe you are thinking of [execFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) or [spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)? And `open` certainly does accept a URL. From `man open`: "If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL."

Comment: What platform are you running on?  For example, there's no "open" command on Windows.  Does `open http://www.linkedin.com` work for you from a command shell?

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me so long to respond. I'm using Windows, so you're right, I've had to use the start command, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

To diagnose and fix this, I would try:

1. In your terminal (not using Node), verify that `open http://www.linkedin.com` works at all. You should see your default web browser open to the appropriate URL. If that doesn't happen, then Node can't magically fix it. Most likely, you'll need to [set the default browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en).
2. Wrap the URL in single quotes just for good measure. This protects you in some cases where the URL contains certain reserved characters.

   ```
   exec("open 'http://www.linkedin.com'");
   ```
3. Add a callback so you can see the command's output and verify it completed successfully.

   ```
   exec("open 'http://www.linkedin.com'", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
       console.log('err:', err);
       console.log('stdout:', stdout);
       console.log('stderr:', stderr);
   });
   ```

The ideal solution is to use [opn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn), a high-quality module that already exists for this exact purpose.

Comment: You're welcome. I also added a link to an npm module that would fix this even better (works cross-platform). If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, use the `start` command instead of `open` (which is for Mac) as below:

```
exec("start http://www.linkedin.com");
```